# Wordpress - Successfully moved site from one server to another, but subpages not working

Tags: wordpress

I just moved a wordpress site from one server to another and the site is working great, but only for the main page but other pages do not work, example. I created a page called Test and when I goto that page www.example.com/test it does not work....how come and how can I fix this?

Comment: does this server have `mod_rewrite` enabled? and can you confirm you've moved the `.htaccess` file too? it is hidden by default on most FTP clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May Be updating permalink solve your problem. Log in to your admin panel take settings->permalinks just update it by clicking save changes. Don't need to change your previous option. Just try this ,may be it will help .

Answer (score 0):

It must be the .htacces, anyway you should ask to the hosting providers.

I let you my .htaccess configuration.

This file is regularly in the root folder of the web.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sendy
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```